# Top Menu bar not working in My Wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress, header

I have two meny=u bar in my site. 1st- top menu 2nd- primary menu.Top Menubar not working in my site.I input it from menu but not working. I use hostme theme. My site http://www.dewdropzone.asia . My topmenu bar header code. See this theme demo for understand what top menu bar not show my site . [click here](http://themeforest.net/item/hostme-premium-hosting-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/164563)

```
<?php if(get_option("topblackmenu") == "true") { ?>
    <div class="topmenu">
        <div class="inner">
        <!-- .top_menu -->
        <?php if (has_nav_menu( 'top-menu' ) ) { wp_menu_functon(); }?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .top_menu -->
<?php } ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="header">   
    <div class="inner">

            <!-- logo -->
            <div class="logo">
            <?php if($s_logo){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $s_logo; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />   
            </a>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <!-- logo -->

            <div class="sec-menu">
            <?php if (has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) { wp_primary_menu_functon(); }
            else{
                echo('<ul class="nav"><li>'.__('Go to WP-admin Appearance Menus and assign menu location', 'hostme_front').'</li></ul>'); 
            } ?>
            </div>
            <!-- topmenu -->

            </div>
</div><!-- topbar -->
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: not working means... when i imput any category in top menubar. and save it. then i go homepage but not show top menubar.

Comment: see this demo theme for what menu don't show in my site.http://themeforest.net/item/hostme-premium-hosting-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/164563 .

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry for adding an answer, but I don't see an option to comment in the question. Am I missing something?

Did you create your navigation through the Appearance>Menus in your Dashboard?
Make sure that you select the menu you have created as your 'Header Menu'.

Comment: yes i make it. but not show. i make it like my primary menu bar. go my site you can see my primary menu bar. bat not show top menu bar.

Comment: I'm trying to understand here:
The navigation bar that currently shows in your website has the following options: 
HOME | WEB HOSTING | DOMIN | SERVICE | Contact us | Hotline

In some of them there's also a sub-menu.

Are you trying to add one more menu at top of that?

PS: I guess you were meant to write 'DOMAIN' instead of 'DOMIN'

Comment: i think you don't understand what i want to say. i have two menu. top manu and primary menu.ths options: "HOME | WEB HOSTING | DOMIN | SERVICE | Contact us" called my theme primary menu. it's work good but top menu not showing.